# How to create LWC custom List view component based on Logged in User filter criteria

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninglistview

Please suggest how to implement Custom List view in LWC which will filter the records based on logged in user and other field criterias because in List view I am unable to define the user information in filter criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be possible with standard list view  you dont need lwc custom component.

you just have to create a formula field  on object   to   check logged in user  is the concerned user or not.
in formula field   you can use    $User.Id   to get current user id   which you can use to compare   with your concerned user lookup field.   and in list view you can add a filter  if this formula field is true or not.

Comment: I tried but it throws the exception in the list view configuration that :  Error: The value $User.Id is only allowed in Mobile Configuration Filters. Also I created a formula field and it is returning true but in Listview its not showing the records related to the user

Comment: you have to create a formula field   to compare current user.   not directly use $user.id   in list view filter.  did you created formula field?

Comment: you have to create formula field as per your requirement current user should see which record.   lets say you have user lookup on current object (user_lookup__c).  and you want to check if this user is logged in and should see list view records.   formula will be something like this   :    IF( user_lookup__c = $User.Id, True, False)

Comment: Actually I want to show the User's Application based on contact lookup related to case. Lets say if the community user is logged in and his application is assigned to a queue but the contact has his id then it should show his application but it is only considering the owner id then it is showing the records in the listview. I have put if (User.id==contactId,true,false) on case and even formula is returning true it doesnt show the records under list view.

Comment: for community users there is a contact field on user.  you can check if that field works for you.   IF( contactid = $User.contactid, True, False)    assuming you are using standard contact field on case otherwise you can replace first contactid  in if condition with api name of contact field.

Comment: Yeah I am using the same formula field , but  it is still not working. I tried hitting the recordid in the url and checked if I am able to access it with community user then I found it is showing the record. dont know what is the issue now. ..in the upper comment I have tried user.contactid.. typing error.

Comment: if you go to record logged in as community user.  this formula field is showing true or false  on layout.    and have you included this as filter in list view?

Comment: Yes.. Everything is showing perfectly fine. I have just tried creating formula like User.contactId==CustomLookupfieldUser and don't understand how come this is working but  not that.... Anyway  thanks for bearing me. Thanks a lot for the help.